# Installing packages with an alt-installed Python 2.6 on CentOS 5

Tags: centos, python

Alt-installed python 2.6 (from source using make altinstall)along side 2.4 on a CentOS machine (so as to not break anything), but I am a bit baffled about how to install python packages to the 2.6 directory tree rather than the stock 2.4 tree CentOS installs.

trying to get the mysqldb python package installed with no luck.

for setup.py I've tried different --home --prefix etc... flags and nothing seems to work.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question [here](http://blog.milford.io/2010/08/new-method-for-installing-python-2-6-4-with-mysql-python-on-centos-5-5/).